# Calling local ASPNET Core 3.1 WebApi from Android or iOS emulator

Tags: android, asp.net-core, xamarin.android, iis-express

**UPDATE**
This is now working. As I suspected the fact that the 127.0.0.1 binding was not showing when I looked at the IIS Express tool window did point at the bindings having not worked.

The trouble is I cannot be sure what caused them to suddenly start working.

127.0.0.1 now appears as a 3rd binding. The only thing I remember changing was going into Project Properties on the API project and editing Debug|Web Server Settings|App URL. I changed "localhost" to 127.0.0.1 as per a suggestion I read elsewhere on SO. I have since chnaged that back to localhost and the 3rd binding is still present.

**END UPDATE**

I am trying to access an ASPNET Core 3.1 WebApi running in IIS Express on my local development machine from either the Android Emulator or iOS Simulator.

My end goal is an Azure B2C secured PUT api called from Xamarin but for now I have pared that back to an unsecured GET endpoint.

I am aware that Android uses a reserved IP address of 10.0.2.2 to map onto my development machine's loopback device. Therefore the request I am making is `http://10.0.2.2:54124/build-version`

I have updated the site element adding a new HTTP binding in applicationhost.config in the "myrepo\.vs\myproject\config" folder

```
    <sites>
      <site name="WebSite1" id="1" serverAutoStart="true">
        <application path="/">
          <virtualDirectory path="/" physicalPath="%IIS_SITES_HOME%\WebSite1" />
        </application>
        <bindings>
          <binding protocol="http" bindingInformation=":8080:localhost" />
        </bindings>
      </site>
      <site name="breathe.patient-service" id="2">
        <application path="/" applicationPool="breathe.patient-service AppPool">
          <virtualDirectory path="/" physicalPath="C:\Projects\MB\breathe.patient-service" />
        </application>
        <bindings>
          <binding protocol="http" bindingInformation="*:54124:localhost" />
     
<!-- NEW BINDING FOR ANDROID -->

          <binding protocol="http" bindingInformation="*:54124:127.0.0.1" />
          <binding protocol="https" bindingInformation="*:44312:localhost" />
        </bindings>
      </site>
      <siteDefaults>
        <!-- To enable logging, please change the below attribute "enabled" to "true" -->
        <logFile logFormat="W3C" directory="%AppData%\Microsoft\IISExpressLogs" enabled="false" />
        <traceFailedRequestsLogging directory="%AppData%\Microsoft" enabled="false" maxLogFileSizeKB="1024" />
      </siteDefaults>
      <applicationDefaults applicationPool="Clr4IntegratedAppPool" />
      <virtualDirectoryDefaults allowSubDirConfig="true" />
    </sites>
```

VS 2019 is running as Administrator and from there I launch the WebApi in IISExpress.

If i enter http://localhost:54124/build-version or https://localhost:44312/build-version into a browser on the development machine the api is called and responds as expected.

If I enter http://10.0.2.2:54124/build-version into chrome on Android emulator I get Bad Request - Invalid Hostname.

If call that endpoint from within Xamarin Android using HttpClient not surprisingly i also get 400 badRequest.

Having read [Debugging .NET Core API on Android Device](http://www.mattruma.com/debugging-net-core-api-on-android-device/) I was expecting to see my additional binding appear in the IISExpress app window but it doesn't.

[image]

What am I missing?

Comment: Instead of posting "UPDATE", you might post an answer and accept it.

Comment: I'm holding off doing that becuase I don't want to give some definetive answer when I'm not totally certain what fixed it.

Comment: https://blog.lextudio.com/how-to-let-android-emulator-access-iis-express-f6530a02b1d3 Most technical details can be found in this blog post, so it is not hard to find a definitive answer.

Comment: I know you got it working, but for others you can avoid having to do the IIS Express binding stuff by using our VS extension called Conveyor.